# Open form in webpart from a list in another webpart

Tags: web-part, form

I have on one page, two webparts. The top part is the list of submitted forms created from infopath, while the second part is the actual form in the window.

What I would like to do is when I submit a form, the page refreshes and shows up in the webpart above. However, when I click on the form at the list in the upper portion, I would like the form to be opened in the lower web part. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

To select from a list of previously submitted forms (either list forms or InfoPath browser forms) and have the form display on the web page you will need to:

1. Add two web parts to a page – 1) the list or library where the forms are saved and 2) an InfoPath Form Web Part
2. Configure the web parts.
3. Create a connection between the list or library and InfoPath Form Web Part.  After the connection is established you will be able to select a form from the list or library and it will display in the InfoPath Form web part.

Step by step instructions can be found on my blog here:  http://jennyssharepointtips.wordpress.com/2014/08/08/display-infopath-forms-or-list-forms-in-an-infopath-form-web-part/

Answer (score 0):

Usually we add a Calculated field in the list and write HTML in it to call a JavaScript method on click of link and place the JavaScript in a hidden Content Editor Web Part...

You can use [TextToHtml on blog.pathtosharepoint](http://www.pathtosharepoint.com/HTMLcc/default.aspx).. to convert the Calculated Field text into HTML content...

In JavaScript you can call a Modal Dialog where you redirect to a page which contains form, so once the Modal Dialog is submitted you can refresh the parent page and the list will show the added results...

JavaScript for Modal Dialog can be:

```
function test() { 
     //debugger; 
     SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ 
        url: "/Lists/ListName/NewForm.aspx", 
        title: "Add item", 
        allowMaximize: true, 
        showClose: true, 
        width: 800, 
        height: 600, 
        dialogReturnValueCallback: refreshCallback 
    }); 
}; 

function silentCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) { 
} 

function refreshCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) { 
     SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK); 
}
```